# Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: File res/drawable-v21

Tags: android, xamarin, resources, xamarin-android-player

I'm creating a class library in Xamarin.Android platform and having XML files in `Resources/drawable-v21 folder.` While running the library in **`API 23, API 24`** then the app is running successfully. But while running the library in `API 21 or API22` then the library throws `"Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: File res/drawable-v21/btn_XXXX.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020055" exception at the  this.SetButtonDrawable(Resource.Drawable.btn_XXXX); line.`

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

note: I'm running it in **5.7" Lollipop (5.0) XXHDPI Phone (Android 5.0 - API 21)** emulator

Comment: Clean, rebuild, delete the bin and obj folder, restart VS.

Comment: I have tried everything but it occurs only in Lollipop OS devices

Comment: did you solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

It is throwing the exception because when running on lower android versions it looks for the file in the drawable-v21 folder:

Those drawable folders are actually for providing device compatibility

What you should do:
create btn_XXXX.xml in your drawable-21 folder or delete the folder leaving only the main drawable folder except you want do specify different drawable files based on different android versions